# Multiple Navigation-Drawer Content onclick action

Tags: java, android, class, navigation-drawer, toolbar

Have a basic activity which implemented custom toolbar&navigation drawer. Had no problem until add some buttons on the main layout. I assigned multiple drawer xml files under menu folder. So my problem is, when I click toolbar hamburger icon, "R.menu.activity_main_drawer1" content coming correctly. when I click on a button on activity,, my other menus comes too. Problem starts there. having 2 issues on my solutions.
toolbar hamburger icon disappearing or 
menu contents not coming correctly.(when i click on button first, "R.menu.activity_main_drawer2" coming right, after closing drawer, if i click on toolbar menu, same "R.menu.activity_main_drawer2" appearing again.)
Hope I could explain. Thanks in advance.

```
public class index extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.index_p_activity);

    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finans);
    one.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kayit);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(index_p.this, drawer, toolbar, "open", "close");
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

     NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.getMenu().clear();
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer1);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.finans:
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(index_p.this, drawer, toolbar, "open", "close");
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.getMenu().clear();
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer2);
            break;
    }
}
```